# Easy way to create new task on Mechanical Turk, using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I've manually created a template and a task on Mechanical Turk. What's the easiest way to now programmatically (in Ruby) create a new task, where:

1. I reuse the task template I've already created
2. I upload to MTurk a CSV file with some different data
3. I can download the raw results CSV programmatically as well

? Is there some Ruby library that already makes this easy, or would I have to dig into the API itself?

I've seen [rturk](https://github.com/mdp/rturk) and [Turkee](https://github.com/aantix/turkee), but they seem a little complicated -- I don't actually want my questions to reside on an external site (in the rturk case), and I don't need a Rails app (in the Turkee case -- I couldn't actually get Turkee working with a Rails app anyways).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to some folks more familiar with the Amazon MTurk API, and apparently the API doesn't allow to use templates (like in the web UI). Rather, you have to loop through submitting a bunch of individual HIT items.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [this fork of rturk](https://github.com/alexch/rturk). As you can see [in the specs](https://github.com/alexch/rturk/blob/master/spec/builders/question_form_builder_spec.rb) it lets you build Amazon-hosted QuestionForms using either XML or [a Ruby DSL](https://github.com/alexch/rturk/blob/master/spec/example_question_form.rb).

Hope that helps!